# Replace getter setter with reflection in spring.xml

Tags: java, spring, reflection, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a populator without any business logic.

```
public void populate(final PaymentModeModel source, final PaymentModeData target)
    {
        target.setCode(source.getCode());
        target.setName(source.getName());
        target.setDescription(source.getDescription());
    }
```

I have seen code in the past where simply entering the attribute names in the `spring.xml` file will do the trick and I can get rid of the entire populator class.
It involves reflection.

Comment: I would not advise using reflection for this.  If someone unwittingly changes a property name, the compiler won’t be able to flag the error.  Is it really so bad to do it this way?  It doesn’t take that long to write.

Comment: @VGR : that would still be a problem. If someone changes a property name then I have to create a new DTO class anyway, by modifying the beans class!

Comment: No you don’t.  The whole point of public methods is that they allow the internal implementation to change without causing friction for callers of those methods.  Is there some requirement that PaymentModeModel and PaymentModeData have to have exactly the same method names at all times?

Comment: There are no requirements but PaymentModeModel is created in the database while  PaymentModeData can be created by simply creating entries in the beans.xml

Answer (score 1):

New hybris versions has orika mapper and it is used for occ. Maybe you saw this. You can also use it but performance won't same as manual coding.